# Mysql Trigger and Event together?

Tags: mysql, triggers, cron, rdbms

I have a before insert trigger:

```
    DELIMITER //
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS product_before_insert //
    CREATE TRIGGER product_before_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON product
    FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
      IF NEW.created_on='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
       SET NEW.created_on = NOW();
       SET NEW.modified_on = NOW();
       SET NEW.expires_on = ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY);    
     END IF;
    END;//
```

Well now I want to take the New.created_on as a TIMESTAMP and add a 15 day interval so that one flag(a bool column) in my product table named product.new is set false which is by default true.e.g:

```
       new boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 1  #table name:product
```

So can I do like:

```
    DELIMITER //
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS product_before_insert //
    CREATE TRIGGER product_before_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON product
    FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
      IF NEW.created_on='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
       SET NEW.created_on = NOW();
       SET NEW.modified_on = NOW();
       SET NEW.expires_on = ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY);

       CREATE EVENT newflagsetter
       ON SCHEDULE AT NEW.created_on + INTERVAL 15 DAY
       DO
         UPDATE product SET new=0;

     END IF;
    END;//
```

Thanks a lot for any answers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the documentation says:

[13.1.11. CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

> ...
>
> You can create an event as part of a stored routine, but an event
> cannot be created by another event.

I think it is outdated, because we read the following:

[E.1. Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

> ...
>
> **Event Scheduler Restrictions**
>
> - ...
> - An event may not be created, altered, or dropped by a stored routine,    trigger, or another event. An event also may not create, alter, or    drop stored routines or triggers. ([Bug #16409](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16409), [Bug #18896](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18896)).
> - ...

Comment: Well then.. it's an event limitation. What do I do now. I can do it in my controller(i am on php-codeigniter now) but that will also require me create an event driven function I mean if 15 day's past from the creation day then an automatic function triggered to set that flag to FALSE. Any in-database idea? Thanks..your answer was great..